# Unable to access BIOS

Tags: boot, system-installation, bios, vaio

I switched to Ubuntu a while back and over time entropy and inexperience lead to a bunch of redundant applications, a very messy directory tree and general slowness. I figured rather than upgrade to 14.04 I would do a clean install.

I created a bootable USB and attempted to reach the BIOS so as to change the boot order. I've tried pressing, clicking repeatedly and holding <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Pause</kbd>, <kbd>Vaio</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>, but none worked.

I figured I'd manually disable starting up in Ubuntu with `sudo rm -rf /`. I just ended up booting in Grub. I took the hard drive out, when booting up it now says:

> Operating System Not Found

Do I not have a BIOS or something? What the heck is going on?

Comment: It says "Operating System Not Found" because you removed the only one it has installed. Have you consulted your user manual to check how to access the bios?

Comment: What model Vaio do you have?

Comment: @Braiam I don't, it's a hand-down from a now deceased relative, couldn't find any documentation CD's with it.

Comment: @BrianGlick Sony VAIO VPCEH2F1E I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone has BIOS (Basic Input/Output System).
Without it, no computer can boot.
About opening BIOS - look at [this](http://www.sony-asia.com/microsite/vaio/htmlmanuals/20123Q/SVD1121/eng/contents/04/21/02/02.html).
Then open Boot tab.
There are options, I haven't VAIO to tell you right.

Answer (score 2):

The BIOS access key for your device is `F11`.  Press it repeatedly while the vaio logo is on the screen.

The full user manual is here: http://download.sony-europe.com/pub/manuals/consumer/AE2H100111.zip

Within that zip, the instructions to boot from external USB are here: `AE2H100111/eng/contents/02/04/01/01.html`