# Restarting BIOS after dual boot failure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, bios, boot-repair

I have the problem I explain in another question, [Dual boot isn't working; cannot come back to Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399866/dual-boot-isnt-working-cannot-come-back-to-windows) which was closed bc is off-topic, but fortunately I received some useful advice.

Considering that the black screen and the PC booting Ubuntu automatically starts happening when I change BIOS configuration, disabling Fast Boot and CSM Support, and since that moment I haven't seen the manufacturer logo and neither reaching the BIOS again, I wanna ask if, considering this, the solution cannot be restarting the BIOS.

At this point, I don't know even if it's possible reaching BIOS at booting bc any button works to me (or i'm not doing it well)

I read that I could physically reset BIOS by **removing CMOS battery and a seconds later putting it again.**
If I do it, wouldn't I reset the initial configuration that always gave me access to Windows? Or the only way is the process of deleting and renstalling an Ubuntu Supported version?

I know that maybe the question is not accurate at all, and could be closed, but would be good to receive some answer before bc I don't know a lot and I'm really stuck with this. Thanks.

Comment: this is an Ubuntu software site - but you have a hardware problem. I'd rather ask the vendor of your hardware. I vote to close it since is has nothing to do with Ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455831/unable-to-access-bios)

Comment: Although you don't see ```press FSomething to enter BIOS``` and those other things, doesn't mean you cannot enter it. It is just hidden due to a setting in ```Grub``` called ```quiet splash```. You don't have to open your PC and remove the battery for a BIOS reset. Just press the usual button to enter into your BIOS. <br>PS If you take out the battery, leave the battery out for a minute or something, not a few seconds (that is too short as the motherboard has capacitors that keep current and will power the BIOS chip, so it won't reset).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)